# fundamental theorem of algebra in the complex plane

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, proof-writing, upper-lower-bounds

My question is about the following lemma (where the Extreme Value Theorem is assumed);

$(1)$Let $f : \mathbb{C} → \mathbb{C}$ be any polynomial function. Then there exists a point $z_0$ $∈ \mathbb{C}$ where the function $|f|$ attains its minimum value in $\mathbb{R}$.

$Proof.$ If $f$ is a constant polynomial function, then the statement of the Lemma is trivially
true since $|f|$ attains its minimum value at every point in $\mathbb{C}$. So choose, e.g., $(z_0) = 0$.
If $f$ is not constant, then the degree of the polynomial defining $f$ is at least one. In this
case, we can denote $f$ explicitly as in Equation (3.1). That is, we set

$f(z) = a_n$ $z^n + · · · + a_1z + a_0$

with $a_n≠0$. Now, assume $z ≠ 0$, and set $A = max${|$a_0$|, . . . , |$a_{n−1}$|}$.$ We can obtain a lower
bound for $|f(z)|$ as follows:

$|f(z)| = |a_n|$ $|z|^n$ $|1 + ((a_{n-1}/a_n)(1/z))$ $+...+$ $((a_0/a_n) (1/z^n))|$

I'm missing the second part of the inequality because I don't know how to format it, but if anyone would like to do so for me you can find it on page 34 of this link,
https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~anne/linear_algebra/mat67_course_notes.pdf

My question, however, is about why one can obtain a lower bound like this, why does it work and how does it help us to prove statement $(1)$.

I'd appreciate secondary sources for further reading as well, and for a bonus explain why this relates to linear algebra.

Comment: You didnt say what $R$ is.

Comment: The set of real numbers and C is the set of complex numbers sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the proof is that a continuos function on a compact set is bounded and attains its bounds.

In your case you choose a sufficiently large R such that for $|z|>R$ the terms $|\frac{a_i}{z^n}|$ are negligible and therefore the value of $f(z)$ is approximately equal to $a_nR^n$. Moreover, on the compact set $|z| \leq R$, p is continuous and therefore bounded below by some M >0 and moreover this is attained. For R large we can ensure $R^n|a_n| > M$ and therefore M will be a global minimum and it will also be attained.

Comment: I should have given a little more background about myself but long story short I have not been working with higher level mathematical notation for a while so could you give me a 'dumbed down' explanation and or perhaps geometric interpretation of what's going on.

Comment: Maybe a simple way to put it is that for large values of |z|, |p(z)| is large. Therefore the least value of p if, it exists, can only be obtained within some closed disk around the origin. And within any closed disk, a minimum is always attained, because p is continuous and, to put it broadely, p(z) is close to p(w) if z is close to w and therefore p cannot be unbounded in the disk, but I am afraid that there is a bit more background needed to fully understand the rigorous justification :( please ask anything you don’t find clear in my explanation and I can try to explain it better